# Selenium web driver. how o test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Iam very new to selenium. So here I have few doubts about working with Selenium.We are following *keyword driven test* in selenium,reading test from excel and object.property file exist for mapping of data from excel and program.Reports are generating using ExtentReport.

> The doubts are, my web application includes saving of Data,that got
>   reflected to many pages based on different criteria.For example
>   Administrator can add the assets,that means he is the custodian of
>   that asset.The saved asset got populated to a a table below, with a
>   unique number asset number. He can transfer his asset to any of the
>   employee in his office or another office.If he tranfer aseet to an
>   employee of his office a OTP is generated to him, that he have to
>   enter for approval.If it belongs to employee of different office,
>   admin do not have the privilage to approve. OTP will be generated to
>   the employee of other office. This is bit complication. Really what
>   Iam facing is how to automate this scenario using webdriver .

Second is How database testing done.Is database testing is used for the above scenario.How to compare data in the below table with excel data.

Kindly suggest. Pls forgive if any mistake asked

Comment: Show us your tried code.

Comment: > 1st )execute.java 
> 
> It is executed.Here UI operation is called
> 
> 
> UIoperation operation = new UIoperation(webdriver);   
> operation.perform(allObjects, keyword, objectName,
>         objectType, value,testcaseid,Steps);

Comment: 2nd-UIoperation.java
>  public void perform(Properties p,String operation,String
> objectName,String objectType,String value,String testcaseid,String
> Steps) throws Exception{
>         System.out.println("");
>         switch (operation.toUpperCase()) {
> >         case "GETTEXT":
>             //Get text of an element
>             driver.findElement(this.getObject(p,objectName,objectType, value)).getText();
>          
> >             break;
>         case "GOTOURL":
            //Get url of application
            driver.get(p.getProperty(value));
            break;

Comment: and Excel sheet with

(Headings)Test case Keyword Object ObjectType value(Headings)

Reset Login In Application GOTOURL url SETTEXT penNo name 1000000